# AWS Terraform - Code Build to Elastic Container Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to deploy AWS CI CD pipeline, where the developer commits in AWS Commit and AWS build will take of care of the building the docker image and pushes it to Elastic Container Registry. From the ECR to ECS fargate the deployment should be done.

I have tried it to do, I need help in fetching the docker image url from code build to move it to ECR. Find the below code

```
resource "aws_codecommit_repository" "repo" {
  repository_name = var.repository_name
  description     = var.description
  default_branch  = var.default_branch

  # Tags
  tags = var.tags

}

# Triggers
resource "aws_codecommit_trigger" "triggers" {
  count           = length(var.triggers)
  repository_name = aws_codecommit_repository.repo.repository_name

  trigger {
    name            = lookup(element(var.triggers, count.index), "name")
    events          = lookup(element(var.triggers, count.index), "events")
    destination_arn = lookup(element(var.triggers, count.index), "destination_arn")
  }

}

resource "aws_ecr_repository" "my_sample_ecr_repo" {
  name = "my-sample-ecr-repo" 
}

resource "aws_codebuild_project" "codebuild_project" {
  name          = "sample-code"
  description   = "Codebuild demo with Terraform"
  build_timeout = "120"

  artifacts {
    type = "NO_ARTIFACTS"
  }

  source {
    type            = "CodeCommit"
    location        = lookup(var.repository_name)
  }

  environment {
    image                       = lookup(var.codebuild_params, "IMAGE")
    type                        = lookup(var.codebuild_params, "TYPE")
    compute_type                = lookup(var.codebuild_params, "COMPUTE_TYPE")
    image_pull_credentials_type = lookup(var.codebuild_params, "CRED_TYPE")
    privileged_mode             = true

    dynamic "environment_variable" {
      for_each = var.environment_variables
      content {
        name  = environment_variable.key
        value = environment_variable.value
      }
    }
  }

  logs_config {
    cloudwatch_logs {
      status = "DISABLED"
    }

    s3_logs {
      status = "DISABLED"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  name = "my-cluster" # Naming the cluster
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "my_sample_task" {
  family                   = "my-sample-task" # Naming the task
  container_definitions    = <<DEFINITION
  [
    {
      "name": "my-sample-task",
      "image": "${aws_ecr_repository.my_sample_ecr_repo.repository_url}",
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 3000,
          "hostPort": 3000
        }
      ]
      "memory": 512,
      "cpu": 256
    }
  ]
  DEFINITION
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"] # Stating that we are using ECS Fargate
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"    # Using awsvpc as our network mode as this is required for Fargate
  memory                   = 512         # Specifying the memory our container requires
  cpu                      = 256         # Specifying the CPU our container requires
  execution_role_arn       = "${aws_iam_role.ecsTaskExecutionRole.arn}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecsTaskExecutionRole" {
  name               = "ecsTaskExecutionRole"
  assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_policy.json}"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecsTaskExecutionRole_policy" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.ecsTaskExecutionRole.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}


resource "aws_ecs_service" "my_sample_service" {
  name            = "my-sample-service"                             # Naming our first service
  cluster         = "${aws_ecs_cluster.my_cluster.id}"             # Referencing our created Cluster
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.my_sample_task.arn}" # Referencing the task our service will spin up
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"
  desired_count   = 1 # Setting the number of containers to 3

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.target_group.arn}" # Referencing our target group
    container_name   = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.my_sample_task.family}"
    container_port   = 3000 # Specifying the container port
  }

  network_configuration {
    subnets          = ["${aws_default_subnet.default_subnet_a.id}", "${aws_default_subnet.default_subnet_b.id}", "${aws_default_subnet.default_subnet_c.id}"]
    assign_public_ip = true                                                # Providing our containers with public IPs
    security_groups  = ["${aws_security_group.service_security_group.id}"] # Setting the security group
  }
}

resource "aws_default_vpc" "default_vpc" {
}

# Providing a reference to our default subnets
resource "aws_default_subnet" "default_subnet_a" {
  availability_zone = "ap-south-1c"
}

resource "aws_default_subnet" "default_subnet_b" {
  availability_zone = "ap-south-1b"
}

resource "aws_default_subnet" "default_subnet_c" {
  availability_zone = "ap-south-1a"
}
resource "aws_security_group" "service_security_group" {
  ingress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port   = 0
    protocol  = "-1"
    # Only allowing traffic in from the load balancer security group
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.load_balancer_security_group.id}"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0 # Allowing any incoming port
    to_port     = 0 # Allowing any outgoing port
    protocol    = "-1" # Allowing any outgoing protocol 
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] # Allowing traffic out to all IP addresses
  }
}

resource "aws_alb" "application_load_balancer" {
  name               = "test-lb-tf" # Naming our load balancer
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  subnets = [ # Referencing the default subnets
    "${aws_default_subnet.default_subnet_a.id}",
    "${aws_default_subnet.default_subnet_b.id}",
    "${aws_default_subnet.default_subnet_c.id}"
  ]
  # Referencing the security group
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.load_balancer_security_group.id}"]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "load_balancer_security_group" {
  ingress {
    from_port   = 80 # Allowing traffic in from port 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] # Allowing traffic in from all sources
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0 # Allowing any incoming port
    to_port     = 0 # Allowing any outgoing port
    protocol    = "-1" # Allowing any outgoing protocol 
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] # Allowing traffic out to all IP addresses
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "target_group" {
  name        = "target-group"
  port        = 80
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  target_type = "ip"
  vpc_id      = "${aws_default_vpc.default_vpc.id}" # Referencing the default VPC
  health_check {
    matcher = "200,301,302"
    path = "/"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${aws_alb.application_load_balancer.arn}" # Referencing our load balancer
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"
  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.target_group.arn}" # Referencing our tagrte group
  }
}
```

Comment: What does "but can't able to fully write it" mean? Does the code work? Are there any errors?

Comment: "I have tried it to do, but can't able to fully write it." is a statement, not a question. Please edit your question to include what exactly you need help with. Please don't expect strangers on the Internet to run your code and start working out what is wrong with it. Be specific about the exact part that you need help with.

Comment: │ Error: expected source.0.type to be one of [CODECOMMIT CODEPIPELINE GITHUB S3                                     BITBUCKET GITHUB_ENTERPRISE NO_SOURCE]